# Core Data "garbage collection"

Tags: core-data

Does CoreData provide something akin to garbage collection (or reference counting) so that entities can be **automatically** removed from the persistent store if they are not referenced by other entities?

Generally, entities are "root entities". Once created they will exist until explicitly removed.

However, I would like to label some entities as not being root entities. These should only exist provided another entity references them that is ultimately referenced by a root entity.

As a **concrete example**, perhaps **User** entity has many (possibly shared) **Document** entities. **User** is flagged **root** and exists until explicitly removed. **Document** is not flagged **root**, and only exists provided one or more **User** reference it.

Thanks.

Comment: By 'removing the entities' you mean removing them from the memory, or from the persistent store?

Comment: Thanks – the latter. Will update.

Comment: Looks like I need to read up on Delete Rules. And that possibly automatic deletion of shared entities is not supported.

Comment: Could you specify a minimum count on the inverse relationship (ie. Document must have at least 1 User), so you get a validation fail if it ends up orphaned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data has delete rules as mentioned.  You can set up a delete rule on the relationship between `User` and `Document` so that when the `User` is removed any associated `Document` entities will be deleted with it.

This is not "garbage collection" as that implies releasing memory that is no longer being used but is referential integrity management so that the data store does not have dangling entities. However it is up to the developer to define what the rules are using the object model editor.

> If the documents relationship on User specifies Cascade, and a Document is shared by a group of User, will it be deleted if any User referencing it is deleted? Or is it only deleted when the last User referencing it is deleted?

If you have a many to many and set up a cascade then yes it would delete the child on the first parent that is deleted. If you need to delete a child when there are no references left then you will need to handle that in code in a subclass of the parent entity. I would suggest looking at the `-prepareForDeletion` method.

Comment: Thank you. (I should probably have said "automatic memory management" as that wouldn't imply the mechanism of management). If the `documents` relationship on `User` specifies `Cascade`, and a `Document` is **shared** by a group of `User`, will it be deleted if any `User` referencing it is deleted? Or is it only deleted when the last `User` referencing it is deleted?

Comment: If you have a many to many and set up a cascade then yes it would delete the child on the first parent that is deleted.  If you need to delete a child when there are no references left then you will need to handle that in code in a subclass of the parent entity.  I would suggest looking at the `-prepareForDeletion` method.

Comment: BTW, "automatic memory management" also implies management :)

Comment: :-) Yes! …But it doesn't imply a _specific mechanism_: garbage collection / reference counting / restarting the system when memory runs out. So, basically, Core Data _doesn't_ have automatic memory management in the general case. That `prepareForDeletion` looks like what I need. Thank you – may I edit your answer to add the clarification?